# How can I make a virtual method properly? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism

Here is what I have:

```
class Abstract
{
public:
  virtual bool isThis(Abstract*);
};

class FileType:public Abstract
{
public:
  bool isThis(FileType* ptr)
  {
    return false;
  }
};
```

And this is what Visual Studio sais:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Make `isThis()` pure virtual if you truly want Class Abstract to be abstract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you do not provide code for the function in `Abstract`, you have to make it virtual pure (adding `= 0`at the end). Then, the signature of the function in the derived class has to be the same (i.e. accepts an `Abstract*` parameter instead of `FileType*`).

I *strongly* suggest you to read some C++ manuals before. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that it couldn't find an implementation of `Abstract::isThis(Abstract*)`; this appears correct, since the code snippet you provide doesn't have a definition of this function.

If the idea is for this to be a pure virtual function, then add `= 0` to the end of the declaration (before the `;`. But then you'll get a further error, because `FileType` doesn't override that function: `FileType::isThis(FileType*)` doesn't have the same argument list.